# Animated GIF encoder for Android

Tags: android, gif

What's the most performant way of producing animated GIFs for Android? I have a set of bitmaps that I need animated. It works fine with the AnimatedGifEncoder class floating around the internet, but performance wise it is extremely slow. Are there any other methods of encoding a set of bitmaps to an animated GIF?

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for same thing as well!.Do let me know if you found a faster way to create a GIF using  multiple images

Comment: I got some feedback this one is way faster : https://github.com/dragon66/android-gif-animated-writer

Comment: See here: https://github.com/dragon66/android-gif-animated-writer/issues/2

Answer (score -1):

Android actually can decode and display animated GIFs, using android.graphics.Movie class.

This is not too much documented, but is in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html.

Moreover, it is used in https://code.google.com/p/apidemos/source/browse/trunk/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapDecode.java#103
example with some animated flag.

thanks to 
Pointer Null

Comment: But that doesn't really encode an animated GIF does it? For showing the animated gifs I am already using a WebView - I'm mostly out after a performant encoding method.